# Get value from Table A if exist else get value from TABLE B. If multiple values are found return MT to indicate multiple types

Tags: sql, sqlite

Get value from Table A if exist else get value from TABLE B. If multiple values are found return MT to indicate multiple types.

For example, if trying to lookup a name that has 'c' and type = 'SW'

the following result is expected

```
Name   | NUM | ID   | TYPE
--------------------------
Carrot | 789 | C456 | MT
Celery | 891 | E891 | SW
```

**Fiddle**
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ipmwJwpru4ZmroGQJwpdjP/0

**Food table**

```
Name   | NUM | ID
-------------------
Apple  | 123 | A234
Orange | 456 | B789
Carrot | 789 | C456
Cherry | 234 | D123
Celery | 891 | E891
```

**Number_type table**

```
NUM | TYPE
----------
123 | SR 
123 | AD 
456 | SW
567 | SP
891 | SW
```

**ID_type table**

```
ID   | TYPE
-----------
A234 | SW 
B789 | AD 
C456 | SW
D123 | SP
C456 | AD
E891 | FJ
```

**Expected Results**

```
Name   | NUM | ID   | TYPE
--------------------------
Apple  | 123 | A234 | MT
Orange | 456 | B789 | SW
Carrot | 789 | C456 | MT
Cherry | 234 | D123 | SP
Celery | 891 | E891 | SW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking of two left joins and conditional logic:

```
select
    f.name,
    f.num,
    f.id,
    case when coalesce(n.min_type, i.min_type) = coalesce(n.max_type, i.max_type)
        then coalesce(n.min_type, i.min_type)
        else 'MT'
    end as type
from food f
left join (
    select num, min(type) min_type, max(type) max_type
    from number_type 
    group by num
) n on n.num = f.num
left join (
    select id, min(type) min_type, max(type) max_type
    from id_type 
    group by id
) i on i.id = f.id and n.num is null
where n.num is not null or i.id is not null
```

In [your db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/91mq7UfB97PJZgmWkMY8RH/0), this produces:

```
| name   | num | id   | type |
| ------ | --- | ---- | ---- |
| Apple  | 123 | A234 | MT   |
| Cherry | 234 | D123 | SP   |
| Orange | 456 | B789 | SW   |
| Carrot | 789 | C456 | MT   |
| Celery | 891 | E891 | SW   |
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for the specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do this

```
   select a.name
         ,a.num
         ,a.id
         ,case when count(distinct nt.type)>1 then
                    'MT'
           when count(distinct it.type) > 1 then
                    'MT'
           when max(nt.type) is not null then
                max(nt.type)
           when max(it.type) is not null then
                max(it.type)
      end as type_computed
     from food a
left join num_type nt
       on a.num=nt.num
left join id_type it
       on it.id=a.id
group by a.name
         ,a.num
         ,a.id 


+--------+-----+------+---------------+
|  NAME  | NUM |  ID  | type_computed |
+--------+-----+------+---------------+
| Apple  | 123 | A234 | MT            |
| Carrot | 789 | C456 | MT            |
| Celery | 891 | E891 | SW            |
| Cherry | 234 | D123 | SP            |
| Orange | 456 | B789 | SW            |
+--------+-----+------+---------------+
```